# Access Data Variable from one class in another class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Before anyone says its a similar or duplicate question of xxxx question, I have checked 27 questions till now and none of them is able to clear myquery and help me, most possibly coz no one posted the question in its most simplest form.

So I have a NS String in Class 1 in which I store some data.

```
##Class 1 
.h
@property ..... NSString *str; 

.m
-(void) someMethod { 

self.str = @"Blah blah"; 

}
```

Now I want to access this "Blah Blah" data from the property "str" in Class 2 without passing it via any methods or such. I just need to access it somewhere (for example lets say viewDidLoad). What would be the most simplest way ?

PS:I was thinking to create a *tempString variable in appdelagate.m and access it in w/e class I want by creating a AppleDelegate *apdg object and accessing it. Any other ideas ?

Comment: @Unheilig How else do you think I am storing the data lol, ofc it is called. Its not that data isnt accessible, I want to know ~how~ to access it.

Comment: `without passing it via any methods` - Why? You're asking us to help you build something nasty and saying 'please don't tell me how to do it properly'... This isn't the responsibility of the app delegate and (probably) shouldn't be done with a singleton.

Comment: @Wain so I need to access the data in `viewDidLoad` or say some method of a 3rd party controll/class which I cant call manually, how do you think will I pass it via method then ? I know how to pass with a method, but thats not the cause and problem here.

Comment: use the singleton class, it will be easy for move the variable from one class to anyother class

Comment: he wants to pass a simple string and he doesn't wants to make a method for delegate

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can you post a tutorial/article or sample code relating to that ? Googling on singleton didnt helped me much last time

iosLearner, I had like to keep it as simple as possible since its just temporary data I fetch from my API which I want to access in other class (which actually is a feedback form)

Comment: What is this text then? Should you be storing it in user defaults? The controller which has the text would usually pass it to the controller which needs it (especially if it was a 3rd party controller).

Comment: @Wain let me explain a bit more. The text is a unique ID which I fetch from my API, that ID will be unique for the view's data (its a game data actually). The 3rd party class I need to use this id/string is a Feedback form with multiple classes. I cud have stored in NSUserdefault but this str is for temporary use and always changes each time view is loaded

Comment: Is the view guaranteed to be loaded before the string comes in? Or the string coming in always happens before the view is shown (but is not the trigger for the display)? It's possible that you should have a singleton feedback controller which makes the request, stores the string and displays the feedback view...

Comment: Class1 VC is loaded 1st, str is loaded in a property string manually after that and hen the feedback VC is called (2nd class)

Comment: There is design pattern called dependency-injection which you might look into.

Comment: @Abizern I did d-injection a while ago in Java. But have you got a reference to doing that in Objective-C / iOS? I never heard of d-injection in terms of Obj-C / iOS. Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig It's just a pattern - you pass an object the information it needs. It's part of "tell, don't ask". For example - when you pass information to a VC in a segue method - that's DI.

Comment: @Abizern Interesting. Never knew seque is based on the DI pattern. Can you elaborate more on how that is made possible with seque conceptually? It was much more work in Java, as far as I remember.. Thanks.

Comment: The Segue isn't - I was using it as an example of where DI __could__ be used.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I was away due to New Year and when I am back now and wanted to test your code, that answer is no longer available. Did you remove your answer and code ? Was it wrong somehow ? If possible, can you post it again so I can check if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SecondViewController.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *textblah;
```

In `FirstViewController.m`

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

// where you want to store value

SecondCiewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
secondViewController.textblah = stringToStore;

// and 
[self.navigationController push:secondViewController animated:YES];

// You can log the set value with to check whether it was successful or not.
NSLog(@"textblah: %@", textblah);
```

For complete understanding of the code and process you can watch the video tutorial like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNmZEXNQheE) and [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZWT0IV8FrI)

You will find them informative and easy to understand specially beginners.

Comment: I know this will work, using it atm in many cases but as I said, I need to access the data in a 3rd party class's code from my custom class. I dont mind creating this variable in that 3rd party class rather then my own class but it will make data management a bit cumbersome

Comment: Its my own php API which grabs a unique gameID for the game which is shown in class 1 VC
 let me explain a bit more. The text is a unique ID which I fetch from my API, that ID will be unique for the view's data (its a game data actually). The 3rd party class I need to use this id/string is a Feedback form with multiple classes. I cud have stored in NSUserdefault but this str is for temporary use and always changes each time view is loaded

Comment: 1. `NSString`s should be `copy`, not `strong` or `retain`. 2. You do **not** need to `@synthesize` anymore (the compiler does that for you), but *if* you do make sure you `@synthesize textblah = _textblah` to avoid accessing the instance variable directly by accident. 3. I don't know what `NSLog(@"/@", textblah);` is supposed to do, but it's not logging `textblah`'s value. To use a variable in a string use `%@`, so `NSLog(@"textblah: %@", textblah);`.

Comment: @SaadChaudhry sorry for taking quite a long for testing it, was busy in class/other stuff and watching tuts, I was able to do this via the delegate singleton way you mentioned and linked tutorial for, can you add a edit to your answer with tut links and mentioning delegate/singleton way, that might help others who stumble upon this since many might not see the comment

Comment: Got error: "MainViewController.m:54:32: No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController' declares the selector 'push:animated:"