# Pass image from camera to view from storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

Something strange is happening with my code.

Scenario: Open camera->Take picture->Pass the image taken to a viewcontroller(from a storyboard.

The thing is that my UIimage variable from the destination view is not available, not recognized!

My code

```
 postviewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface postAlertViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *cameraImage;
@end

 postviewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   UIImageView *aImageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, self.view.frame.size.width,150 )];
    aImageview.image=cameraImage;
    [self.view addSubview:amageview];
}
```

Take picture and pass it to the view controller above

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    ViewController *postView = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postview"];
    postView.cameraImage=(UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:postView animated:YES];
}
```

The stroryboard ID is set to "postview". 
What i am getting is:

```
Property 'cameraImage' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'
```

Why `cameraImage` is not available from the origin view although is declared in destination's .h file?

In another situation where i needed to pass a string between views, in same manner as above

```
[yourViewController setValue:mysc.title forKey:@"sendAlertTitle"];
```

worked ok.

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: you want to show your image inside someother viewcontroller?

Comment: I think i explained it. From View1 push a button,open camera,take picture,pass picture to view 2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858693/access-data-variable-from-one-class-in-another-class/20858773#20858773

Comment: in your case secondViewController.imageview.image = firstimageview.image;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
postAlertViewController *postView = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postview"];
```

and always use class and interface name start with capital

Comment: :( i had to include  postviewController.h and use  postviewController *postview and not ViewController. Simple! Thank you! I'll accept when i can.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this one for more ease.

```
- (IBAction)captureImage:(id)sender
{
    if (! [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *deviceNotFoundAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Device" message:@"Camera is not available"
                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [deviceNotFoundAlert show];

    } else {

        UIImagePickerController *cameraPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        cameraPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        cameraPicker.delegate =self;
        // Show image picker
        [self presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}



-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{

    UIImage *selectedImage =[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    ViewControllerName *Vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"captioEdit"];

    Vc.postImgStr=[self scaleAndRotateImage:selectedImage];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:captioViewEdit animated:YES];
}

//Delegate method of UIImagePickerController for image picker model cancel
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Thanks